# Reset the POST data

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I wonder if it's possible to clear all of the POST data in  a form? Reset everything in `$_POST` and clear it, with other words.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm currently using a nice and clean jQuery function that clears all of the textfields, checkes and select's in the current form. After the reset of these fields, the POST information (as we can call it) is still in the browser. There for I asking you if it's possible to clear the POSt data too trough jQuery. zerkms below says it's impossible though :/

Comment: oh, from that point. It is not clear from the original question. So, in this case just follow [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) strategy. It is common and good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has nothing to do with `$_POST` as long as it works on *client side*.

> all of the POST data in a form

For the client there is no difference in source of the data used to fill the form.

> Reset everything in $_POST and clear it

As I said previously - jquery works in client's browser, so when jquery takes the control, it is too late, because POST has already been passed and processed

Comment: Ah, okay, so this is in other words impossible?

Comment: @Erik Edgren: yes, it is impossible by definition

Comment: Okay :/ That's just... bad but in the same way understandable ^^